# What data type to use in MySQL to store images?

Tags: mysql

I need to store image and resume of user in the data base.

I am using mysql data base and php5. I need to know which data types I should use.

And also how do  I set a limit (maximum size) for uploaded data.

Comment: i just want to know that which data type support the image files in mysql database. i much familiar with varchar,date , timestamp etc . if u have any idea plz suggest me.

Comment: Common guys, he's very obviously not a native speaker. I've tried to refactor the question. @rasjon: please verify I didn't change the intended meaning.

Comment: There are many, many related or even duplicate questions about this, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=storing+images+in+mysql

Answer (score 34):

What you need, according to your comments, is a '[BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)' (Binary Large OBject) for both image and resume.

Answer (score 9):

Perfect answer for your question can be found on MYSQL site itself.refer their manual(without using PHP)

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914

According to them use **LONGBLOB** datatype. with that you can only store images less than 1MB only  by default,although it can be changed by editing server config file.i would also recommend using MySQL workBench for ease of database management

Comment: won't longblob slow down searching for something?

Comment: @iamme not unless you're querying against the column that's a `longblob`. If you have the columns, ("image_name" varchar, "image_data" longblob) for example, and you query `image_name`, then no, it won't be any slower.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done from the command line. This will create a column for your image with a `NOT NULL` property.

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`pic` (
`idpic` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`caption` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
`img` LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`idpic`)
)
TYPE = InnoDB;
```

From [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,17671,27914)