# Image being returned in text from database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have selected a row from the database, within the row is a field called image. This is a blob datatype which contains an image within the database but when i try to display the image via php it displays the text version of the image not the actual image.

```
<?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
$player = $this->player;
$name = $player->forename . " " . $player->surname;
$handed = $player->handed;
$image = $player->image;
?>

<div class="thumbnail"><?php echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $name . '" />'?></div>
```

It is probably an easy fix and i did look at trying:

```
$mime = "image/jpeg";

$b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($image["img"]);
echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
?>
```

but that only outputed:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/w==" alt="">
```

Any help is much appreciated, thankyou in advance

Comment: You shouldn't be storing images as blobs. The database should contain file path to image.

Comment: It looks like your images was not saved correctly.

Comment: @davidstrachan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475065/what-data-type-to-use-in-mysql-to-store-images      This post says to use blobs to store images. When using workbench and selecting the field I can view the image. The database is returning the text format of the blob and not the actual image. I am wondering is it possible to return the image or is the only way to do it by linking to the file path?

Comment: You could try the GD function `imagecreatefromstring()`see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php